# reallocating memory for an array c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was looking on [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) reference and found the dynamic memory management and
 was looking at the function that reallocate memory and I was wondering if this function could be used to make an array bigger I think that is what they mean but I really don't understand this line

```
more_numbers = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));
```

this appears in the example on cplusplus reference
so here is my question in a nutshell

can `realloc()` be used to make an array bigger? thanks :)

Comment: Use vectors or similar if you need resizable containers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if the memory for the array was allocated via `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` earlier. Otherwise you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Where "asking for trouble" is a polite way of saying "Undefined Behavior", which is also a politer way of saying "Anything can happen, your program could crash, it could delete the contents of your hard-drive or get your girlfriend pregnant"

Answer (score 0):

"The function may move the memory block to a new location, in which case the new location is returned". Even though it preserves the data in your block, any pointers to the objects inside this block may become invalid.